# Splunk : tstat count over nested fields using spath and groupby doesnt return result

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

On splunk, I have a data set as follows, under say index "market-list":

```
{ Resource: {
        Fruit: mango
        Type: sweet 
       } 
        Attribute: {
         color: yellow
          from: { 
            place: argentina
            continent: southamerica
          } 
       }
    actions: [{ export : yes }]
 }
```

I want to use tstat as below to count all resources matching a given fruit, and also groupby multiple fields that are nested.

I tried:

```
| tstats count | spath | rename "Resource.Fruit" as fruitname | search fruitname=mango where index=market-list groupby fruitname Attribute.from.place actions{}.export
```

expecting something on the lines of:

```
| tstats count where "Resource.Fruit"=mango index=market-list groupby fruitname Attribute.from.place actions{}.export
```

This however does not return any result. Any suggestions on how to use spath with tstats for the above? I tried looking up but wasnt able to get the solution I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `tstats` command only works with fields that were extracted at index time.  Since `spath` extracts fields at search time, it won't work with `tstats`.

`| tstats count | spath` won't work because `tstats` only returns a number with which `spath` can do nothing.

Comment: What would be the suggestion? I tried without spath but was not able to access the nested keys

Comment: Don't use `tstats`.  If you need speed, consider creating an accelerated data model.  Use can use `tstats` on that.